# vim doesn't indent properly with filetype plugin indent on

Tags: javascript, json, vim

I have `filetype plugin indent` on in my ~/.vimrc, but it screw up the indentation for JSON objects.

I'm starting vim with `vim -N -u NONE <filename.js>`

And I enable `:filetype plugin indent on`
and `:set sw=4 fileetype=javascript`

This is what I'm getting:

```
var foo = {
    Bar: function(){
         },
    Baz: function(){
         } 
};
```

This is what it should be -- is there a way to get this?:

```
var foo = {
    Bar: function(){
    },
    Baz: function(){
    } 
};
```

The reason I enabled the indent plugin is so block commenting was easier. If I type `/* <enter>` it will assuming I'm doing a block documentation comment. But if it butchers my JSON ending brace, I will avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

I have [this indent script from Ryan Fabella](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1936); it indents your example as you want.